# More efficient data structure

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

I'm developing a project and I need to do a lot of comparisons between objects and insertions in lists.
Basically I have a object of type Board and I do the following:

```
if(!(seenStates.contains(children[i])))
{
    statesToExpand.addToListOrderly(children[i]);

    seenStates.insertHead(children[i]);
}
```

where statesToExpand and seenStates are two lists that I defined this way:

```
typedef struct t_Node
{
    Board *board;
    int distanceToGoal;
    t_Node *next;
} m_Node;

typedef m_Node* m_List;

class ListOfStates {
...
```

Everything works fine but I did some profiling and discovered that almost 99% of the time is spent in operating on these lists, since I have to expand, compare, insert, etc. almost 20000 states.

My question is: is there a more efficient data structure that I could use in order to reduce the execution time of that portion of code?

## Update

So I tried using `std::vector` and it is a bit worse (15 seconds instead of 13 with my old list). Probably I'm doing something wrong... With some more profiling I discovered that approximately 13.5 seconds are spent searching for an element in a vector. This is the code I am using:

```
bool Game::vectorContains(Board &b)
{
    clock_t stop;
    clock_t start = clock();
    if(seenStates.size() == 0)
    {
        stop = clock();
        clock_counter += (stop-start);
        return false;
    }

    for(vector<m__Node>::iterator it = seenStates.begin(); it != seenStates.end(); it++)
    {
        if( /* condition */ )
        {
            stop = clock();
            clock_counter += (stop - start);
            return true;
        }
    }
    stop = clock();
    clock_counter += (stop - start);
    return false;
}
```

Can I do something better here or should I move on to another data structure (maybe an `unordered_set` as suggested below)?

### One more update

I tried the exact same code in release mode and the whole algorithm executes in just 1.2 seconds.
I didn't know there could be such a big difference between Debug and Release. I know that Release does some optimization but this is some difference!

Comment: Use an `std::vector`?

Comment: Once I read that a vector is not efficient if its size grows continuously, as it would be in my case. Is it true?

Comment: From your description I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you describe in a few sentences what is your problem? without getting into details of implementation you did.

Comment: Once I read that speculating about performance is a complete waste of time. Try it, measure it and compare results.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm getting tired of that "use a std::vector" answer, it should be automatically inserted by a filter or something

Comment: Apparently `std::vector` can outperform a linked list even for insertions/deletions because linked lists often cause the CPU cache to miss (non contiguous allocation). So it might be worth seeing if that gives good results in your case.

Comment: @minomic: srd::vector::push_back is amortized O(1).

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve? From the little information in those code snippets, it appears you are building a priority queue and a set. For both of these there are vastly more effective (w.r.t. time complexity and usually also real performance) data structures than lists or vectors could ever hope to be. A vector is usually a better sequence than a linked list, but maybe a sequence is not what you need.

Comment: Ok, I will try some alternatives and see which one performs better.
@KerrekSB: "Once I read" was a way to shorten my comment, but I remember well where I read it: "Thinkink in C++" by Bruce Eckel, paragraph "Cost of overflowing allocated storage". It says that every time the size grows all the objects are copied and the old ones are destroyed. This is why I did not want to try a std::vector. But I will give it a try.

Comment: @minomic: We can play the dig-up-the-authority game all day long (my quote comes from Howard Hinnant, paraphrased), but that doesn't change the fact that you have measure.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ok, anyway I did not want to sound polemic. Just trying to motivate my choices... But you're right: I can measure.

Comment: `std::vector` seems *no* good choise for your kind of requirements. As far as I understood, you need fast search and fast insertion. Both are O(n) for a vector. Use a `std::map` instead, where both are O(log n). [But note that using the latter doesn't mean you will directly get faster execution times, as that depends on the number of elements]

Comment: @davidhigh: Ok, I will try another structure, even if in Release mode I have excellent results even with `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your data structure resembles a singly linked list. So, instead of usong your own implementation, you can try to work with a

```
std::slist<Board*>
```

or probably better with a

```
std::slist<std::unique_ptr<Board> >
```

If you further also need the reference to the previous element, then use a standard `std::list`. Both will give you constant insertion, but only linear lookup (at least if you don't know where to search).

Alternatively, you can consider using a `std::map<std::unique_ptr<Board> >` which will give you logarithmic insertion and lookup, but without further effort you lose the information on the successor.

**EDIT**: `std::vector` seems *no* good choise for your kind of requirements. As far as I understood, you need fast search and fast insertion. Both are O(n) for a vector. Use a `std::map` instead, where both are O(log n). [But note that using the latter doesn't mean you will directly get faster execution times, as that depends on the number of elements]

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
if(!(seenStates.contains(children[i])))
```

for a linked list is going to be very slow. While the algorithmic time is `O(n)`, same as it would be for a `std::vector<Node>`, the memory that you're walking over is going to be all over the place... so you're going to incur lots of cache misses as your container gets larger. After a while, your time is just going to be dominated by those cache misses. So `std::vector` will likely perform much better.

That said, if you're doing a lot of `find()`-type operations, you should consider using a container that is setup to do find very quickly... maybe a `std::unordered_set`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a list ends up with O(n) time to search for elements. You could consider data-structures with more effiecient lookßup, e.g. std::map, std::unordered_map, a sorted vector, other tree-structures. There many data-structures. Which one is best depends on your algorithm design.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you don't want to use a linked list in your case. Looking for a specific value (ie contains()) is very slow in a linked list, O(n).

Thus using an array list (for example std::vector) or a binary search tree would be smarter, complexity of contains() would become on average O(log n).

However if you are worried about expanding your array list very often, you might make it take a lot of space when you create it (for example 20 000 elements).

Don't forget to consider using two different data structures for your two lists.